# Wordpress 2.8+ and IE8 display problems?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, internet-explorer-8, wordpress-theming, ie-developer-tools

**EDIT:** Corrected the site header IE7 code in my original post. Have tried that and inserting **X-UA-Compatible: IE=EmulateIE7** into the header without any success. Both of these steps are suggested by Microsoft here:

```
http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2008/06/10/introducing-ie-emulateie7.aspx
```

I'm working on a Wordpress blog (URL: www.nxtbot.com) and have encountered some problems with how the blog renders in IE8. The site uses Wordpress 2.8+ and the Mandigo Wordpress theme.

The primary design of the page has one central content window, with two sidebars on the right side of the page that use and display widget elements.

The site loads and displays perfectly when viewed with Chrome, Firefox, and Safari, but breaks when viewed with IE8: Both sidebars disappear, and only the main content window is visible.

I've tried inserting this into the site header...

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
```

...to force IE7 compatibility, but that didn't seem to help.

Anyone else encountered this problem, or have a fix/workaround?

Comment: after IE7 is it really a question mark or just a typo? obviously should be a double quotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your use of  to position the content and the sidebar is a really bad idea, but that is not the problem with IE8.

the real problem is that you have an unclosed object tag in post 228 and that eats the rest of the page. As your sidebars are after the content then they disappear.

What you should do (except fixing the broken markup, of course) is to stop using tables and instead draw the sidebars in divs that are right floated, and put them before the content in the HTML. The result would be properly positioned sidebars that are rendered before the content and will not disappear if your content breaks the markup.

Comment: Thanks Guss! I fixed the unclosed tag in post #228 and that solved the short-term problem. I'm guessing the other issues you described are related to the theme I'm using (Mandigo), so I'll start looking for another theme. Any suggestionson that front?

Comment: Its a matter of personal taste, I guess :-). I'm not much for 2 sidebar layouts (I think they are too busy). On a new blog I created today I used iNove which I think looks really nice and has 4 customizable sidebar locations (even if they are all one after the other in the default markup).

Answer (score 0):

" is misssing after content attribute, if that isn't tying mistake.